# Scala Assembly hangs at kubernetes gitlabrunner pod

Tags: scala, kubernetes, jvm, gitlab-ci

I have a K8S Cluster and gitlabrunner pods connected to it.

So that when I run the `sbt assembly` command on this gitlabrunner build phase, gitlab runner return timeout exception to me and pipeline FAIL.

I have fetched all `jstack <PID>` outputs and it return WAITING-parking, according to these message I have removed all resource limit to gitlab runner .

I want to build my app but it hang too long building and downloading the dependencies .

Please help!

Comment: I am getting same hang problem even locally. Previous project that assembles now hangs. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Hello @ibaralf , in my case I was building applications on docker-in-docker these create hanging issue on heapstack (my comment from  jstack) according to this , I 'm transport build to the directly scala pods instead of dind pods on kubernetes